# How to stop WebStorm opening files you have just saved over?

Tags: ide, webstorm

In JetBrains WebStorm I often drag files from one location to another in the project explorer in order to override the file at the location I drag to.

WebStorm has an annoying habit of opening the file that has just been overridden when I do this.

Can this behavior be switched off? I can't find anything in the documentation or menus that suggests it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy:** just uncheck the corresponding check box in copy/move confirmation dialogs:

[image]

[image]